# Test coverage in REST Assured

Tags: rest-assured, test-coverage

I am planning to use RESTAssured for API Testing in our project.

I am wondering if any mechanism is available to determine the test coverage.

I did google search but didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what kind of coverage?
-Requirement
-Code
-Endpoint
-Method
-Bug
-Environment
-etc.

I guess endpoint and/or requirement coverage you want to earn: Create a coverage matrix where you mark the covered endpoint and its method (y axis) with test case (x axis). The input endpoints can be granted in prior since you should know them. The rest can be collectet in runtime with a collector util.

I personaly used a custom annotation for tests where I marked the used endpoint(s) whilst the test result was provided by testNg ITestListener. At the end with a custom reporter I made my own coverage result as a heatmap.